# Connect between Android app and network on hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I created a network on the hyperledger composer locally. I can deal with this network as an admin but I will update this later to deal as a user.

My question is how can connect an Android app to this network locally?

And this connection will need an internet connection?

I need this app to participate and create assets and make transactions as I can do on hyperledger composer.

How can do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your Android App talk to Hyperledger network using REST API's.
you can create REST API's using composer-rest-server
checkout instructions at this url
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/applications/web.html